# Difference between two list with same 'list' type (with and without apostrophe ' ')--python

Tags: python, list, token, spacy

I have got two lists, list_1 is defined by me directly, the other is generated by using an operation in spaCy, they both return a 'list' type, but they are obviously different, one with '  ', one without '  '.

**Question_1:**

are they both totally the same type of list in python?

```
import sys
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Token
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

list_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'this is a dog']
print(list_1, type(list_1))

sentence = 'apple and orange and banana this is a dog'
doc = nlp(sentence)
list_2 = []
for i in doc.noun_chunks:
    list_2.append(i)
print(list_2,type(list_2))
```

**Output:**

```
list_1: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'this is a dog'] <class 'list'>
list_2: [apple, orange, banana, a dog] <class 'list'>
```

**Question_2:**

How to solve the following error?

I assume they are totally the same (type), but when I use the list_2 as a normal list, in the following code, it returns an error.

```
for i in list_2:
    if "dog" in i:
        print(list_2.index(i))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-6f9c38535050> in <module>
     16 print(list_2,type(list_2))
     17 for i in list_2:
---> 18     if "dog" in i:
     19         print(list_2.index(i))
     20 

TypeError: Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.token.Token, got str)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what `nlp` does, but the difference between list_1 and list_2 is the type of the elements in the lists.  try printing `type(list_2[0])` and `type(list_1[0])` to see the difference.

Comment: thanks, I just did that, yes, I can see the type(list_2[0]) and type(list_1[0]) are in different type:)

Comment: Ok, next step, if you really want to use `nlp`, try printing `dir(list_2[0])` and see what functions are provided that will allow you to check what each object contains.  I have a gut feeling that if you ask `if "dog" in str(i):` it will probably work.  (Not 100% certain though)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, it works now after using --if "dog" in str(i)-- :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like spacy is giving you an object, not just the text ... when you use nlp, try:

```
for i in doc.noun_chunks:
    list_2.append(i.text)
```

and that should give you a str to str comparison that you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful for me, which lets me re-consider the .text and the span, I have not paid enough attention on them previously, but only considered the printed result, now I see:)